# ORACLE SQL number of customers who have ordered something on a date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables involved, the "customers" table and the "orders" table.

The ***"customers"*** table has the following columns:

```
Customerid, companyname, contactname, contactittle, addresses, city
```

The ***"Orders"*** table has the following columns:

```
orderid, customerid, employeeid, orderdate, shippeddate, shipname
```

I have to do where the number of customers who have ordered a product in the year 97 comes out.

It should be something like

```
Number of clients 20
```

I have tried the following code, but I think it is wrong for the following two reasons

1-I think that like `'%97%'` may cause errors in the future

2-For some reason it takes me the number of orders that have been made, not the number of customers

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT (companyname))as Numero_CLIENTES
FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.customerid=orders.customerid
WHERE orderdate like '%97%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  customers (customerid) as
  3    (select 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual union all
  5     select 3 from dual
  6    ),
  7  orders (orderid, customerid, orderdate) as
  8    (select 100, 1, date '1997-12-02' from dual union all  --> customer 1 counts as "1"
  9     select 101, 1, date '2000-03-28' from dual union all
 10     select 102, 2, date '1997-05-29' from dual union all  --> customer 2 counts as "1" as well
 11     select 103, 2, date '1997-06-12' from dual            --> because both orders were made in 1997
 12    )
```

Query:

```
 13  select count(distinct c.customerid) numero_clientes
 14  from customers c join orders o on o.customerid = c.customerid
 15  where extract(year from o.orderdate) = 1997;

NUMERO_CLIENTES
---------------
              2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is a keyword, not a function.

You can use a date range and put `DISTINCT` inside the aggregation so you get the count of different company names:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT companyname) AS numero_clientes
FROM   customers c
       JOIN orders o
       ON c.customerid = o.customerid
WHERE  orderdate >= DATE '1997-01-01'
AND    orderdate <  DATE '1998-01-01'
```

You could also use either :

- `WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderdate) = 1997`
- `WHERE TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYY') = '1997'`

and it would work; however, in those cases, Oracle would not use any index you have on the `orderdate` column and would need a function-based index on, respectively, `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderdate)` or `TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYY')`. If you use a date range then Oracle can use an index on the `orderdate` column.